# tflearn initialization with numpy.array

Tags: python, initialization, tensorflow, autoencoder, tflearn

I am using tflearn to create a Auto-encoder, now I want to initialize the weights and bias using the learned parameters (np.array) from RBM.

I tried methods such as:

```
w = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=(784, 256), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(w0))
```

for

```
encoder = tflearn.fully_connected(encoder, 256, activation='sigmoid',
                                  weights_init=w, bias_init=b)
```

But I always got the error

```
ValueError: If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.
```

If I use:

```
w = tf.get_variable('w1', initializer=tf.constant_initializer(w0))
```

I got error:

```
    ValueError: Shape of a new variable (w1) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

Can anybody give some suggestions?

Comment: Any recent insight here?

Comment: Any progress???